# PHP Class and inheritance, serialization

Tags: php, inheritance, serialization, extend

Serialized varibale does not seem to retain its state from classes that were extended.

I have a class, called directly from somewhere that accepts a serialized variable:

```
class Main extends Admin {
function __construct($serialized){
    parent::__construct($serialized);
}

.... (omitted)
}  

class Admin extends Page{
    var $pageargs;

function __construct($should_still_be_serialized_form){
    $this->pageargs = unserialize($should_still_be_serialized_form); }}
```

In admin class i get error: unserialize() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in (admin class file)...

Is this the way php handles inheritance? or something is wrong with my code?

Comment: i call new main by:
$args['foo'] = 'bar';
$args['bar'] = 'foo';
$classpage = 'Main';
eval("\$page = \$classpage('".serialize($args)."')");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that $should_still_be_serialized_form is array instead of serialized string. Check out did you pass correct param - print_r($should_still_be_serialized_form).

Comment: a call to the main class is this: (PHP)
$vartoserialize['foo'] = 'bar';
$vartoserialize['bar'] = 'foo';

eval("\$page = new \$classpage('".serialize($vartoserialize)."')"); 
and the events take place as stated above to my very post.

Comment: print_r showed that it was really an array that was passed when i initially created the code and i forgot about it, it should not be there.